# What are the disadvantages (if any) of SystemRandom?

Tags: python, random

Python's `random` library offers the [`SystemRandom()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) class, which provides an interface to `urandom` to generate cryptographically-secure random numbers on platforms that support it.

Other than the fact it makes your code less portable (to architectures lacking `urandom` or similar), and not being  not reproducible for testing, are there any practical downsides to always using `SystemRandom` in place of `Random`?

Comment: It's probably slower than a basic PRNG.

Comment: I can imagine it would be slower in certain circumstances if you had to wait on a pool of entropy, but I wonder if that is true in real use cases.

Comment: urandom doesn't wait on the entropy pool regardless.

Comment: It won't wait on most systems, but since it's the kernel generating the cryptographic random numbers it'll be that much slower because of the kernel/user mode transitions.

Comment: Since it lacks `jumpahead()`, perhaps its not ideal for multi-threaded apps.

Comment: The [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) algorithm is less than 10 lines of code. I doubt even a non-blocking cryptographically secure RNG would be able to compete with that.

Comment: On my system (linux) I've measure it to ~40x slower, but I guess if you're actually doing something with those random numbers (besides generating them) the difference won't be so big.